# Parse the response from Unirest PHP

Tags: php, unirest

I am making a call to the API using Unirest PHP. It looks like this:

```
$response = Unirest\Request::post(
                    "url_to_api",
                         array(
                               "api" => "my_api_key",
                               "Content-Type" => "application/json"
                                )
json_encode(array("parameters" => [100, 200]))
                              );
print_r($response->body);
```

The response body contains a lot if information. This is an stdClass Object. How can I parse this? I tried parsing it as you would in JSON but I get an error. The response looks like this:

```
stdClass Object ( [requestId] => blahblah [status] => Succeeded [elapsedTimeInMs] => 0 [warnings] => Array ( [0] => elapsedTimeInMs is deprecated. Please use the timing headers instead. [1] => status is deprecated. Please use HTTP status codes to determine the status of a request. ) [release] => stdClass Object ( [version] => 13 [commitId] => 275342fakeid5737425 [file] => test.R [function] => add_nums ) [result] => Array ( [0] => 300 ) )
```

All I want is the 300 from the response, that occurs at the very end.

Comment: `$response->body->result[0]`